# Selecting all users' sample and update a field value of the sample

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table called tblItemReviewItems and I have to pick a sample of 10% of ItemReviewId for each UserId in a given date. 
This is the table script and some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE tblItemReviewItems(
   ItemReviewId INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,UserId       VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  ,ReviewDate   DATE  NOT NULL
  ,Deleted      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
  ,Audited      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425282,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425291,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425299,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425304,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425311,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425324,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425333,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425358,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425423,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425443,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425482,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425547,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425580,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425899,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425921,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16426037,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16426239,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16426257,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16426787,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427205,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427428,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427465,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427506,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427545,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427596,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427615,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427841,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427860,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427908,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16428038,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16428200,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16428665,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429222,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429240,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429254,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429275,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429283,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429642,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429653,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429658,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429671,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429691,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429706,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429718,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427072,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427221,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427299,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427628,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16428359,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16428988,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429003,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429346,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430270,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16431587,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16432199,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16433774,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16434065,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16435062,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16435667,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16435702,'jdoe1','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425351,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425396,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425472,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16426042,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16426260,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427379,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427497,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427553,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427568,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427575,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427595,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427613,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427653,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427688,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427698,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427877,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16428006,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16428031,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16428353,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16428375,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16428827,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16428883,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16428929,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429004,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429121,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429138,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429624,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429647,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429776,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429837,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429890,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430032,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430061,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430100,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430158,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430173,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430223,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430311,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430357,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430440,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430471,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425491,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425629,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425722,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16426266,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427719,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427957,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16428401,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429028,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429146,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16431275,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16431558,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16432351,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16432521,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16434592,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16434822,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16435461,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16435562,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16435658,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16435694,'jdoe2','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425249,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425393,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425513,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425575,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425604,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425906,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427509,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16428876,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16428889,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16428937,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16428966,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16428977,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429001,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429036,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429062,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429096,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429118,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429809,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429944,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429984,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430038,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430048,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430115,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430140,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430189,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430339,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430368,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430420,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430439,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430467,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430651,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430656,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430663,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430842,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430846,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430876,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16431068,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16431080,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16431100,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16431475,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16431517,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16431545,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16431572,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16431616,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16431753,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16431792,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16431803,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16431812,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16431833,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','Yes','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16425929,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16427532,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429660,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16429819,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16430204,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16431287,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16432004,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16434233,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16434999,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16435056,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','No','No');
INSERT INTO tblItemReviewItems(ItemReviewId,UserId,ReviewDate,Deleted,Audited) VALUES (16435798,'jdoe3','7/1/2017','No','No');



ALTER PROC [dbo].[spPickSample] 
AS
 BEGIN
   DECLARE @Nos INT = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tblItemReviewItems WHERE Deleted='No' and UserId='jdoe1')
   DECLARE @Yes INT = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tblItemReviewItems WHERE Deleted='Yes' and UserId='jdoe1')
   DECLARE @Samplepct FLOAT =(.05*(@Nos + @Yes)) / @Nos*100
   DECLARE @Percentage AS INT = @Samplepct
     SELECT
        TOP (@Percentage) PERCENT *
     FROM
        tblItemReviewItems
     WHERE
        Deleted='No' AND UserId='jdoe1'
     ORDER BY
        NEWID()
 END
```

5% of population should come from Deleted(No) and 5% of population should come from Deleted(Yes).

Population:

```
+-------------+----+-----+-------------+
|   UserId    | No | Yes | Grand Total |
+-------------+----+-----+-------------+
| jdoe1       | 16 |  44 |          60 |
| jdoe2       | 19 |  41 |          60 |
| jdoe3       | 11 |  49 |          60 |
| Grand Total | 46 | 134 |         180 |
+-------------+----+-----+-------------+
```

Target Sample:

```
+-------------+----+-----+-------------+
|   UserId    | No | Yes | Grand Total |
+-------------+----+-----+-------------+
| jdoe1       |  3 |   3 |           6 |
| jdoe2       |  3 |   3 |           6 |
| jdoe3       |  3 |   3 |           6 |
| Grand Total |  9 |   9 |          18 |
+-------------+----+-----+-------------+
```

This is what I am trying to obtain:

```
+--------------+--------+------------+---------+---------+
| ItemReviewId | UserId | ReviewDate | Deleted | Audited |
+--------------+--------+------------+---------+---------+
|     16427072 | jdoe1  | 7/1/2017   | No      | Check   |
|     16428359 | jdoe1  | 7/1/2017   | No      | Check   |
|     16429003 | jdoe1  | 7/1/2017   | No      | Check   |
|     16429222 | jdoe1  | 7/1/2017   | Yes     | Check   |
|     16428665 | jdoe1  | 7/1/2017   | Yes     | Check   |
|     16425311 | jdoe1  | 7/1/2017   | Yes     | Check   |
|     16426266 | jdoe2  | 7/1/2017   | No      | Check   |
|     16432521 | jdoe2  | 7/1/2017   | No      | Check   |
|     16435694 | jdoe2  | 7/1/2017   | No      | Check   |
|     16427379 | jdoe2  | 7/1/2017   | Yes     | Check   |
|     16427568 | jdoe2  | 7/1/2017   | Yes     | Check   |
|     16427877 | jdoe2  | 7/1/2017   | Yes     | Check   |
|     16427532 | jdoe3  | 7/1/2017   | No      | Check   |
|     16435798 | jdoe3  | 7/1/2017   | No      | Check   |
|     16429660 | jdoe3  | 7/1/2017   | No      | Check   |
|     16430140 | jdoe3  | 7/1/2017   | Yes     | Check   |
|     16430339 | jdoe3  | 7/1/2017   | Yes     | Check   |
|     16428937 | jdoe3  | 7/1/2017   | Yes     | Check   |
+--------------+--------+------------+---------+---------+
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[PickSample]
(
    @ReviewDate AS DATETIME
    ,@UserId AS NVARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tempDashboard table
    (
    ItemReviewId VarChar(50)
    ,UserId VarChar(50)
    ,ReviewDate Datetime
    ,Deleted varchar(10)
    ,Audited varchar(10)
    )

    DECLARE @Nos INT = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tblItemReviewItems WHERE Deleted='No' AND ReviewDate=@ReviewDate AND UserId=@UserId)
    DECLARE @Yes INT = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tblItemReviewItems WHERE Deleted='Yes' AND ReviewDate=@ReviewDate AND UserId=@UserId)
    DECLARE @Samplepct FLOAT =(.05*(@Nos + @Yes)) / @Nos*100

    DECLARE @Percentage AS INT = @Samplepct

    INSERT INTO @tempDashboard (ItemReviewId, UserId, ReviewDate, Deleted, Audited)
    SELECT
        TOP (@Percentage) PERCENT ItemReviewId, UserId, ReviewDate, Deleted, Audited
    FROM
        tblItemReviewItems
    WHERE
        Deleted='No' AND ReviewDate=@ReviewDate AND UserId=@UserId
    ORDER BY
        NEWID()

    DECLARE @Nos2 INT = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tblItemReviewItems WHERE Deleted='No' AND ReviewDate=@ReviewDate AND UserId=@UserId)
    DECLARE @Yes2 INT = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tblItemReviewItems WHERE Deleted='Yes' AND ReviewDate=@ReviewDate AND UserId=@UserId)
    DECLARE @Samplepct2 FLOAT =(.05*(@Nos2 + @Yes2)) / @Yes2*100

    DECLARE @Percentage2 AS INT = @Samplepct2
    INSERT INTO @tempDashboard (ItemReviewId, UserId, ReviewDate, Deleted, Audited)
    SELECT
        TOP (@Percentage2) PERCENT ItemReviewId, UserId, ReviewDate, Deleted, Audited
    FROM
        tblItemReviewItems
    WHERE
        Deleted='Yes' AND ReviewDate=@ReviewDate AND UserId=@UserId
    ORDER BY
        NEWID()
    UPDATE a
    SET Audited='Check'
    FROM tblItemReviewItems AS a
       INNER JOIN @tempDashboard AS b
       ON b.ItemReviewId=a.ItemReviewId
END
```

I have to run the stored procedure for each user. Generally there are around 200 users everyday. So I will have to run the stored procedure 200 times in a day. How do I achieve this in a single go?

Comment: do you have a primary key on tblItemReviewItems ?

Comment: @Jayvee The table has a primary key "ItemReviewId".

Comment: Ok, you can then select top @percentage percent ItemReviewedId into a temp table or table variable or cte and use this to select the items and update them

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: @HABO I have updated the question after reading the post.

Comment: @Jayvee I have updated the stored procedure. Now a for loop might solve the problem. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @LoneRider I edited my answer to show how you can run the stored procedure in a loop.

Comment: @Jayvee Your suggestions would do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spPickSample] 
AS
 BEGIN
   DECLARE @Nos INT = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tblItemReviewItems WHERE Deleted='No' and UserId='jdoe1')
   DECLARE @Yes INT = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tblItemReviewItems WHERE Deleted='Yes' and UserId='jdoe1')
   DECLARE @Samplepct FLOAT =(.05*(@Nos + @Yes)) / @Nos*100
   DECLARE @Percentage AS INT = @Samplepct
   DECLARE @temptable table (ItemReviewId nvarchar(50))
   INSERT into @temptable
     SELECT
        TOP (@Percentage) PERCENT ItemReviewId
     FROM
        tblItemReviewItems
     WHERE
        Deleted='No' AND UserId='jdoe1'

    Update t set Audited="Check"
    from tblItemReviewItems t
    where ItemReviewId in (Select ItemReviewId from @temptable)

    Select * from tblItemReviewItems 
    where ItemReviewId in (Select ItemReviewId from @temptable)

 END
```

suppose your users are in a table called '[users]' then you can loop a cursor in this way:

```
DECLARE @userid nvarchar(50)
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT userid 
FROM [users] 

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @userid   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
     exec dbo.PickSample '2017-07-01',@userid
       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @userid   
END
```

Please note that i hardcoded the reviewdate but you get the picture you may need to adapt it to your specifics

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it - Select the rows into a temporary table. If you have a primary key, you just need to select the primary. If you don't have a primary key, select enough columns for the combination to be unique. Once you have the needed rows in the temp table, join with that temp table and update those rows in the original table with the values you are want. If you don't intend to do anything subsequent with the rows you have selected, you can actually update the rows after doing a select with the correct where clause.